# DataTable checkbox cell does not return null but throws exception when attempting to cast value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I'm having a problem with my .net application where I'm trying to take a value from a DataTable cell and cast it to a bool.

The DataTable is bound to a DataGridView and the cell is a CheckBox.
When I check if that cell is null, it returns as not null. However when I try to get the value, it returns nothing and will not cast it to a bool.
Any help appreciated.

```
        private void dgvItems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                var test = dtItems.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];               

                if (test != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)test)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("true");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("false");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("null");
                }
            }
        }
```

Exception thrown at (bool)test:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

[image]

Comment: Could the value actually be DBNull rather than Null?

Comment: Potentially. Let me check.

Comment: What exactly is DBNull?

Comment: If Dt is a DataTable being mapped, and in your database value is null and a not a Boolean, then it will show as DbNull

Comment: @PaulAlexander DBNull is a non existent value from a database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Okay so If I change the null check to if (test != System.DBNull.Value) it drops straight down into the else and executes MessageBox.Show("null");! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try

Comment: Checking for System.DBNull.Value was the solution. Thanks for your help both :)

Comment: Great to know that, However, Instead of checking for DbNull, you should use bool?. It reduces the coupling of DbTypes in your business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid Cells are ThreeWay Checkbox. They cannot be casted to bool.

Try       bool? instead

```
  bool? testValue=(bool?) dtItems.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];    
  if (testValue!=null&&testValue)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("true");
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("false");
  }
```

Comment: throws an error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: One question, As I rememebr, you need to dtItems.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex].Value

Comment: I was missing the explicit cast operator (bool?).